# firebase error while using google auth npm

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-oauth

I am trying to learn fire base following is the code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithRedirect,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
} from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API KEY",
  authDomain: "crwn-clothing-db-4d333.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "crwn-clothing-db-4d333",
  storageBucket: "crwn-clothing-db-4d333.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDER ID",
  appId: "API ID",
  measurementId: "G-6MLB6CSGZR",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: "select_account",
});

export const auth = getAuth();
export const signInWithGooglePopup = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

following is the sign in

```
import React from "react";
import { signInWithGooglePopup } from "../../../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";

function SignIn() {
  const logGoogleUser = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await signInWithGooglePopup();
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle specific error: auth/popup-closed-by-user
      if (error.code === "auth/popup-closed-by-user") {
        console.log("Google sign-in popup was closed by the user.");
        // Handle this case as needed (e.g., show a message to the user)
      } else {
        console.error("Error during Google sign-in:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sign In Page</h1>
      <button onClick={logGoogleUser}>Sign In With Google Popup</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignIn;
```

I am getting the followin error in the console

Error handling response: Error: Failed to read a named property 'href' from 'Location': Blocked a frame with origin "https://crwn-clothing-db-4d333.firebaseapp.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

at tryShowingMateBar (eval at success (chrome-extension://ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke/src/kernel/kernel.js:233:37), <anonymous>:5428:57)

```
at eval (eval at success (chrome-extension://ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke/src/kernel/kernel.js:233:37), \<anonymous\>:153:17)

at eval (eval at success (chrome-extension://ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke/src/kernel/kernel.js:233:37), \<anonymous\>:108:27)
```

popup.ts:289 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:289

popup.ts:289 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:289

popup.ts:289 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:289

popup.ts:289 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:289

signin.component.jsx:8 UserCredentialImpl {user: UserImpl, providerId: 'google.com', _tokenResponse: {…}, operationType: 'signIn'}

sign-in:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
webpackHotDevClient.js:76 The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.

Can some one guide me what am I doing wrong

I was trying to make an firebase app

Comment: Are you sure you should be sharing your API key?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: I am not sure but I am in learning phase so was I not suppose to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have send my code in the question when I click sign in with google button in my <sign in> component it gives me these errors in console.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED     

Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
popup.ts:289 


Error handling response: Error: Failed to read a named property 'href' from 'Location': Blocked a frame with origin "https://crwn-clothing-db-4d333.firebaseapp.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

popup.ts:289 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:289

Answer (score 0):

```
     const logGoogleUser = async() => {
            const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider() 
            const auth = getAuth(app)
            provider.setCustomParameters({prompt:"select-account"}) // Add this
           
           // Rest of the code
           }
```